# symbol or html entities code did not complied in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to compile symbol in jsx? I have a checking like this

{this.state.something && `&#8226`}

 this won't work it print the string.

Comment: I am not too sure but it should have a semicolon `&#8226;`

Comment: use this: `{this.state.something && <span>&#8226;</span>}` **;** is imp after the value.

Comment: JSX only compiles HTML elements, not HTML entities.

Comment: what is your requirement?Do you want to print the bullet character instead of string?

Comment: @MayankShukla please post an answer, your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question based on my assumption of your question.Please correct me if I didn't get your question.

If you want to have a conditional check: `{this.state.something && &#8226}`

In current scenario `this.state.something` evaluates to true and then it will print the string '&#8226'. It is commonJS behaviour. You can check this in browser console.

If you want to have a condition to which you can do something when it evaluates to true try this:

```
{this.state.check && '&#8226' ? 'print this' : 'do not print this'}
```

if `'&#8226'` does not evaluate the bullet(which is most likely), try `'\u2022'` instead.

P.S. Here is browser console result:

```
var text = ' asdjk ' + '&#8226'; ---> *text= " asdjk &#8226"*

var text = ' asdjk ' + '\u2022'; ----> *text = " asdjk •"*
```

Checking whether bullet is present in text or not:

```
text.includes('&#8226') --->  *false*
text.includes('\u2022')--->*true*
```